# SQL count for the current 7 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get a list of the number of orders entered to our database for the last 7 days. I've tried repeating the below but it becomes some error messages about incorrect format, so I'm wondering what's the correct method.

To get order amount for current day I use `SELECT COUNT(order_number) FROM orders WHERE created = TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY');`

I want a table like:

```
Date        Total Orders
sysdate     500
sysdate-1   400
sysdate-2   300
```

etc. for the last 7 days. Is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason why created is a string column?

Comment: Is this Oracle? Is created a string or date field? Why don't you do a range query on created?

Comment: Can you post example?

Comment: What should happen if there are no orders for a day in the range?  Do you want that day omitted entirely, or do you want to see "sysdate-X   0"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following would work for you:

```
Select created, count(ordernumber)
  From orders
 Where to_date(created, 'DD-MON-YYYY') between trunc(sysdate-7) and trunc(sysdate)
 Group by created
 Order by to_date(created, 'DD-MON-YYYY') desc
```

Note, if you can change it I would seriously consider using a DATE column for created.

Answer (score 0):

You should have mentioned the specific error. I guess created is a date field and you are trying to compare it with a string. If this is the case, here is the statement needed. TRUNC removes the time part from the date.

```
SELECT TRUNC(created), COUNT(order_number)
FROM orders 
WHERE TRUNC(created) BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate) - 6 AND TRUNC(sysdate)
GROUP BY TRUNC(created)
ORDER BY TRUNC(created);
```